# Experiences w/NI Reflektor?

Tags: convolution-reverb

Hi forum,

has anyone of you yet used Native Instrument's new convolution reverb effect "Reflektor"?

What are your experiences? Does it hold its promised features of Zero-Latency and other creative parametrisation? What about the integration in Guitar Rig 4, is this usable for the average Sound Designer at all?

I'm asking because the demos sound very promising, yes, but has anyone used it in a real-world situation?

cheers,
Julian